# <img> not centered horizontally in <ul>

Tags: html, css

I want to make a list of images that are displayed horizontally. The problem is that paragraphs are displayed correctly but images aren't.
My Code:

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="a.png" style="max-width: 20%;">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="b.png" style="max-width: 20%;">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about 1) what is wrong with the way images display, and 2) what is right about the paragraphs (since there are no paragraphs in your HTML snippet)?

Comment: @Kerri well if I replace the <img> tags with <p> they will be displayed next to each other which is what I want to happen but instead the images are displayed vertically. I hope this information helps!

Comment: here, in the snippet, images are horizontally displayed. Can you provide a fiddle or [edit] this snippet to make it reproduce your issue?

Comment: @CalvinNunes oh I see, then I guess the problem isn't the css and/or html then?

Comment: have no idea... the code is yours, is that all the code you have?

Comment: @CalvinNunes no it isn't, it's all the code that's relevant to the images. In the css the only other thing is fonts for h2 tags and in the html the only other thing is the link to the stylesheet and other general stuff (favicons, title, etc.)

Comment: Please, try to [edit] the code in the snippet to reproduce the issue, otherwise the question will be closed as "not reproducible"
When you run the snippet here, the images are displayed as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the inline style you have added to the images. When you apply `max-width: 20%`, there will be a 80% empty space next to them, so that in a large screen, the images will have a large space at their right side, and in smaller screens, they will be displayed vertically because of space.

Simply add a fixed width to your images or use `vw` measures (example: `max-width: 20vw`) in order to the images get a width that is relative to the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

this can easily be done with flexbox by adding display: flex and justify-content: center to the ul. You can also add a flex-wrap to collapse the images on small screens if needed. You'll also need to set padding-left to 0 due to default padding on ul elements I would look into adding a [reset css](https://cssdeck.com/blog/what-is-a-css-reset/) to help with that

```css
    ul {
       justify-content: center;
       display: flex;
       padding-left: 0;
    }

    ul, li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    img {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="a.png" style="max-width: 20%;">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="b.png" style="max-width: 20%;">
      </li>
    </ul>
```